# Binding datagrid columnheadertext to a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm having troubles on the said title.
I have a model that has a collection inside and this collection should also be added on the same level as the other properties of my model.

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
 public int RowNum{get;set;}
 public List<Product> Products{get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
 public string Name{get;set}
 public int Quantity{get;set;}
}
```

The code sample above is just an example but I want the the Product.Name inside the list to be displayed as the columnheader...

The details is working but the binding columnheader doesn't..

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Products[0].Name}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Products[0].Quantity}" />
```

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should display the `Name` of the first `Product` of the first `MyModel` in the header:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Products[0].Quantity}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].Products[0].Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```